# Wpf - Clipping Border corner(dog ears)

Tags: wpf, styles

I need to create dog ears at the corner of my window :

[image]

i clipped the ear out , but i can't figure out how to make it transparent.

XAML :

```
      <Border Background="#5486A5">
            <Border.Clip>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <RectangleGeometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource rectConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" />
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                    </RectangleGeometry>

                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                <LineSegment Point="50,0"/>
                                <LineSegment Point="0,50"/>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Border.Clip>
```

this as the result of the following display :

[image]

okay , first thing any ideas how to make that clipped part transparent ?

secondly , any advice on how to achieve the folded part ,

thirdly , any advice on how to create the DropShadow to look like that , i'm currently using a 
Dialog Window for that screen , but i'm willing to compromise for that DropShadow look and use something like a pop-up .

Thanks in advance , i got no designer experience any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the code you posted is already Transparent behind the clipped corner. Make sure that the control that this border is in doesn't have a Background set to white. It should be `Background="Transparent"`

For the folded corner you can draw it like this:

```
<Polyline Fill="Red">
    <Polyline.Points>
        <PointCollection>
            <Point X="50" Y="0" />
            <Point X="0" Y="50" />
            <Point X="50" Y="50" />
        </PointCollection>
    </Polyline.Points>
</Polyline>
```